# Get JSON children of single node with random name in Groovy

Tags: json, groovy, jsonslurper

In Groovy (not Grails), I want to get the color of such an item:

```
{
    "8436": {
        "color": "red",
    }
}
```

The "8436" number is dynamic, but there is always only one.

I can't use JsonSlurper's `json.8436.color` syntax, because the number would be hard-coded.

How to get the color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option, given:

```
def jsonStr = '''{
    "8436": {
        "color": "red",
    }
}'''
```

You could do:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonStr)

def (rootKey, color) = json.findResult { k, v -> [k, v.color] }

assert rootKey == '8436'
assert color == 'red'
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you know a bit about the structure of your json input, you can take advantage of the fact that the root is a map that contains one key.

Like this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText('{"8436":{"color":"red"}}')
def rootKey = json.keySet()[0]
assert rootKey == '8436'
assert json[rootKey].color == 'red'
```

Comment: Getting the rootKey is a great first step indeed! Unfortunately when I put your code in a file and run it I get `No signature of method: java.util.HashMap$KeySet.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [0]`

Comment: Several solutions to this error to this pop to mind: (1) pick the first item off of the set's iterator: `json.keySet().iterator().next()`, (2) coerce the set to a list and index as before: `(json.keySet() as List)[0]`, (3) start with an empty list and add the set to it then index as before: `([] + json.keySet())[0], and so on, with many variations on the theme.

Comment: BTW, `Iterable.getAt(int)` is defined in Groovy, so I can't imagine why `java.util.HashMap$KeySet` does not recognize it, since that class implements `Iterable` (by way of `Collection`, by way of `Set`). This would seem to me to be a bug in Groovy, but I have been wrong about that before.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I ran the code in groovy console before it was submitted, perhaps we're using different groovy versions (I'm on 2.4.7)? Not sure when `getAt()` was added on Iterator. However, BalRog's suggestion: `keySet().iterator().next()` should work in any groovy version.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 2016.04's Groovy, which is surprisingly old: 1.8.6

Answer (score 0):

Update: better (more idiomatic?) way

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonStr = """
{
    "8436": {
        "color": "red",
    }
}
"""
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonStr)

def color = json.each {}.collect{it.value.color}[0]

println color
```

======= old version, storing in an closure-external variable =======

Why not something like this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonStr = """
{
    "8436": {
        "color": "red",
    }
}
"""
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonStr)

def color
json.each { color = it.value.color}

println color
```

Comment: I never like changing values outside a closure from within a closure :-/